# Error installing Exempi 2.5.2 on M1 Macbook Pro running Big Sur

Tags: python, installation, boost, pycharm, xmp

I'm trying to install [Exempi 2.5.2](https://python-xmp-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) in **PyCharm IDE** for python in order to read Metadata from a Photoshop psd file.

**My code is:**

```
import PIL
from libxmp.utils import file_to_dict
from libxmp import consts
from psd_tools import PSDImage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Hello')
```

**I have installed the following packages in PyCharm:**
ExifRead
Pillow
PyBundle
brew
docopt
packbits
pip
psd-tools3
python-xmp-toolkit
pytz
setuptools

**I get the following Errors:**
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/rajnesh/Python/uploadJpeg2SquareSpace.py", line 9, in 
from libxmp.utils import file_to_dict

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libxmp/**init**.py", line 50, in 
from .core import XMPMeta, XMPIterator

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libxmp/core.py", line 50, in 
from . import exempi as _cexempi

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libxmp/exempi.py", line 69, in 
EXEMPI = _load_exempi()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libxmp/exempi.py", line 60, in _load_exempi

raise ExempiLoadError('Exempi library not found.')

libxmp.ExempiLoadError: Exempi library not found.

Process finished with exit code 1

**The Documentation for [Exempi](https://python-xmp-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) says that I need to have [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) installed.** I wonder whether this is the problem. I'm not sure how to install it in PyCharm, since I don't see it as an option amongst the packages.

Answer (score 3):

I edited my `exempi.py` after using `brew install exempi`

```
def _load_exempi():
    """
    Loads exempi library.
    """
    path = ctypes.util.find_library('exempi')
    if path is None:
        if platform.system().startswith('Darwin'):
            if os.path.exists('/opt/local/lib/libexempi.dylib'):
                # MacPorts starndard location.
                path = '/opt/local/lib/libexempi.dylib'
    if path is None:
        m1_path = '/opt/homebrew/lib/libexempi.dylib'
        if os.path.exists(m1_path):
            path = m1_path
            
    if path is None:
        raise ExempiLoadError('Exempi library not found.')

    if os.name != "nt":
        EXEMPI = ctypes.CDLL(path)
    else:
        EXEMPI = ctypes.WinDLL(path)

    return EXEMPI
```

to be specific, this is what I added.

```
if path is None:
        m1_path = '/opt/homebrew/lib/libexempi.dylib'
        if os.path.exists(m1_path):
            path = m1_path
```

Then it worked.